# What is the possible domain and range for this rational function?

Tags: functions, rational-functions

Given a function:

y= $\frac{(2x^2+11x+15)^{1/2}}{(x^2-9)^{1/2}}$

What is the domain and range for this function?

My attempt:

To find domain, I need to find the value of x such that the function is defined:

$\ (x^2-9)$ >0

$\ (x-3)*(x+3)$ >0

So, we get first domain: x ≠ 3 and x ≠ -3

Another domain is:

$\frac{2x^2+11x+15}{x^2-9}$ >0

$\ (2x^2+11x+15)$ >0

$\ (x+3)(2x+3)$ >0

x= -3 or x= -3/2

At number line, we get the domain should be:

$\ x< -3 or  x > -3/2 $, where x≠ 3 and x ≠ -3.

Is my domain true?

But, how to find the range? it seems pretty hard to find the range for this problem. Can somebody give me a clue or any hints to find the range?

Thanks

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x^2-9}$ exists (and it is real) only if $x\le -3$ or $x\ge 3.$ That is, the domain of your function is different if you write $\frac{(2x^2+11x+15)^{1/2}}{(x^2-9)^{1/2}}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{2x^2+11x+15}{x^2-9}}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to solve two inequalities:
$2x^2+11x+15\geq 0$ and $x^2-9\geq 0$
thus we have
$x\le -3$ or $x\geq -\frac{5}{2}$ from the first inequality and $x<-3$ or $x>3$ from the second inequality.